# Access Denied Error while access BigQuery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am accessing `Bigquery` table of one project (say `P1`) from an application running in app engine in another project (say `p2`).

I have added the `p2@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` as Project Editor in `P1`.

However, when I try to run a query from `P2` application on `P1` table, i get an access denied error.

I am using default application credentials.

Do i need to do anything else?

Comment: Check if `p2@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` is still a valid/listed service account in the `P2` project. Try adding in `P1` that service account with a `BigQuery User` role or a more appropriate `BigQuery Roles` from [Predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined_roles). See also BigQuery's [Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control)

Comment: Yes, p2@appspot.gserviceaccount.com is a valid account. It is the default service account for app engine.I started with BigQuery specific roles for p2 in P1, however since i kept getting an error, I gave Editor role to P2 service account.